# select optionmeneu to be a paramater of my function

Tags: python, tkinter

edI am building a simple translator to map the word of a file to another file that I have and want the language selected in my `Optionmenu` to be one of the parameters for my translation function. Here is my work.

```
 main=Tk()
 main.geometry("800x500")

 val_button=Button(main, text='Translate', command=lambda: execute(main.filename, selected))
 val_button.place(x=600, y=450)

 val_button=Button(main, text='Browse', command=lambda:browser())
 val_button.place(x=600, y=410)

 clicked= StringVar()
 selected = StringVar()


 menu=['Spanish', 'German']

dropdown=OptionMenu(main, selected,*menu)
dropdown.place(x=600, y=30)


def browser():

    main.filename= filedialog.askopenfilename()

def execute(file, selected):
    file_open=pd.read_excel(file)
    map_file= pd.read_excel('referencefile.xlsx', index_col=0)
    df = file_open.rename(columns=map_file[selected])

df.to_csv('translated.csv')

main.mainloop()
```

I am using the the `selected` **stringvar** for the `execute` function and nothing is happenning.

Comment: Nothing sets `selected`. Also should it be `map_file[selected.get()]`?

Comment: I think `select` in this line `dropdown=OptionMenu(main, select,*menu)` should be `selected` instead.

Comment: @acw1668  thanks. but now I have `TypeError: 'PY_VAR39' is an invalid key`.

Comment: You need to change `command=lambda: execute(main.filename, selected)` to `command=lambda: execute(main.filename, selected.get())`.

Comment: @acw1668. thanks, I have the following now `TypeError: 'PY_VAR39' is an invalid key
`

Comment: @TheLizzard thanks. I have the following error now: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: @Herc01 With the code you posted, you can't get that error.

Comment: @Herc01 You need to understand the reason of the proposed changes.

Comment: @TheLizzard thank you for letting me know. I will investigate why I have an error then